# TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Tags: python

Meu código é super simples:

```
import random
jogador=int(input('Qual é a sua jogada?\n1 - Pedra\n2 - Papel\n3 - Tesoura\nEu jogo: '))
jogador=random.randint(jogador)
print('O computador joga {}'.format(jogador))
```

Mas fica dando esse erro que está no título. Não sei qual é esse argumento 'b'.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint), `randint` recebe dois parâmetros: `a` e `b`. O primeiro indica o valor mínimo e o segundo indica o valor máximo. No seu código você só está passando um parâmetro (a variável `jogador`).

Mas no seu caso, o que você precisa parece ser:

```
jogada = random.randint(1, 3)
```

Ou seja, vai gerar um número aleatório entre 1 e 3.

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas se uma jogada é do jogador e outra do computador, não faz sentido guardar ambos na mesma variável. Talvez o que você pretende é algo do tipo:

```
import random
jogador = int(input('Qual é a sua jogada?\n1 - Pedra\n2 - Papel\n3 - Tesoura\nEu jogo: '))
computador = random.randint(1, 3)
print('O computador joga {}'.format(computador))
```